# Creating Sharepoint/MOSS sitemap

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sitemap

I'm trying to create a sitemap for my MOSS publishing site, i've got two approaches but seem to be stuck with both.

My first approach is to use the PortalSiteMapProvider, which is already created and nicely cached...

```
PublishingWeb rootWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb);

//Get the URL of the default page in the web
string defaultPageUrl = rootWeb.DefaultPage.ServerRelativeUrl;

PortalListItemSiteMapNode webNode = (PortalListItemSiteMapNode)PortalSiteMapProvider.CurrentNavSiteMapProviderNoEncode.FindSiteMapNode(defaultPageUrl);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.WriteLine("Top Level: " + webNode.Title.ToString() + "<br />");

//iterate through each one of the pages and subsites
foreach (SiteMapNode smnTopLevelItem in webNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.WriteLine(smnTopLevelItem.Title.ToString() + "<br />");

    //if the current sitemap has children, create a submenu for it
    if (smnTopLevelItem.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (SiteMapNode smnChildItem in smnTopLevelItem.ChildNodes)
        {
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.WriteLine(smnChildItem.Title.ToString() + "<br />");
        }
    }
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

but this seems to return everything in the site collection (e.g. lists, surverys). I only want to show the Sharepoint webs.

My other approach was to use this piece of code..

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://example.org");
SPWebCollection sites = siteCollection.AllWebs;
foreach (SPWeb site in sites)
{
    Console.WriteLine(site.Title.ToString() + " " + site.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString());
}
```

Which is perfect, apart from the problem of returning all the webs in a flat list.

Ideally I want to be able to add indentation to show child webs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the replys everyone, this is what I came up with

```
        public ListSiteMap()
    {
        PortalSiteMapProvider portalProvider1 = PortalSiteMapProvider.WebSiteMapProvider;
        portalProvider1.DynamicChildLimit = 0;
        portalProvider1.EncodeOutput = true;

        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;

        PortalSiteMapNode webNode = (PortalSiteMapNode)portalProvider1.FindSiteMapNode(web.ServerRelativeUrl);

        if (webNode == null || webNode.Type != NodeTypes.Area) return;

        Console.WriteLine(webNode.Title.ToString() + " - " + webNode.Description.ToString());

        // get the child nodes (sub sites)
        ProcessSubWeb(webNode);
    }

    private void ProcessSubWeb(PortalSiteMapNode webNode)
    {
        foreach (PortalSiteMapNode childNode in webNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(childNode.Title.ToString() + " - " + childNode.Description.ToString());

            //if the current web has children, call method again
            if (childNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                ProcessSubWeb(childNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

I found these articles helped

http://blogs.msdn.com/ecm/archive/2007/05/23/increased-performance-for-moss-apps-using-the-portalsitemapprovider.aspx

http://blogs.mosshosting.com/archive/tags/SharePoint%20Object%20Model/default.aspx

http://www.hezser.de/blog/archive/tags/SPQuery/default.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Generally it's a bad idea to use the object model for recursion. It's extremely slow and resource-intensive to do this. `PortalSiteMapProvider` is pre-cached for you and can tear through an entire site structure in milliseconds.

Regarding your question about `SPSite.AllWebs`, that property does return a flat list of all webs. That's what it's for. If you want a list of only the *immediate* child webs, use the `SPSite.RootWeb.Webs` property. Recurse over each `SPWeb` in the `.Webs` property, and call their `.Webs` property in turn to get a tree-view.

Also, when dealing with the object model, make sure to **DISPOSE EVERY WEB AND SITE**. This will cause epic bad problems if you don't. This includes disposing every web in the `.Webs` collection, even if you haven't touched it.

Edit:

To get the PortalSiteMapProvider to return only webs, set its `IncludePages` property to `false`.

Comment: ok cool, i'd like to use PortalSiteMapProvider but i'm unsure how to restrict the output to webs only.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking the type of every node in the foreach loop using the PortalSiteMapNode.Type property and displaying only nodes of type NodeTypes.Area?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this tool:

http://realworldsa.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-tool-for-sharepoint-2007-and-2010.html